# Setting default Datepicker date using PHP session variable date

Tags: php, session, datepicker

I'm setting the date in the Datepicker by using PHP.

The date is set using $_REQUEST and I store this in a session variable.

```
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$_SESSION['date']=$date;
```

The session variable and date is getting set as required.

I set the default datepicker value by using the following PHP script:

```
<div id="divDatePicker" class="input-append datepicker">
                  <?php if($_SESSION['date']){ ?>
                <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['date'];?>"/>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                <input id="filter-date" size="16" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </div>
```

So if the date isn't set by default today's date shows up which works just fine as well.

The problem arises when I navigate to another page.

So my datepicker is on 1.php. When I go to 2.php and navigate back to 1.php via breadcrumbs even though the session variable for date is still set (I can see this using var_dump) the Datepicker does not get set. So what shows up is mm/dd/yyyy in the Datepicker.

Why isn't it getting set to $_SESSION['date'] on navigating back?

Comment: To debug further: Try to put a date hard coded ie:<input id="filter-date" value="2013-11-05" .... > to see if navigating back will show the date. If it shows then you have a problem with your $_SESSION['date'] parameter if not then your problem goes with date picker itself.

Comment: yes it seems to work just fine if it's hard coded.

Comment: Ok then now you can check if you get the same date format from $_SESSION['date']

Answer (score 0):

To display the value in input type date create variable and give this variable the value of session`value="<?php echo $date;?>"`